microsoft clarity session restarted on every page change Shopify App
I'm a Shopify app dev, I have an issue using Microsoft clarity in my Shopify app, when user navigates to different page clarity treats it as new user , so the recordings are broken into peaces on each navigation.
The main issue here is that Shopify doesn't allow cookies,
I tried giving user_id , session_id and page_id values to clarity function, but nothing is making clarity identify the user.
We use the remix template.
Anyone know how to fix this?
I found some similar issues raised in github:
https://github.com/microsoft/clarity/issues/523
https://github.com/microsoft/clarity/issues/175
